# How to use the EventBus onEvent method?

Tags: java, android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm using EventBus in my Android application. In my mainActivity, I have this handler method which sends live data to the EventBus as follows:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case TGDevice.MSG_STATE_CHANGE:
                EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(msg.arg1);
                ...
```

I'm using Fragments class and I need to receive the message from the handler.

I have registered the Fragment class in the onCreateView method as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data_log, container, false);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
}

public void onEvent(Message message){
    tv.setText("Signal" + message);
}
```

And I have the onEvent method which is suppose to be called when there is an Event. Unfortunately, this method is never called. I thought it might be method to be overridden but it doesn't seem to be.

What do i need to do to read from messages from the EventBus?

Also, in debugging modes, where can I see the number of threads being created? (I'm using Android Studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this method is never called

That is because your `onEvent()` takes a `Message`, and (presumably) you are not posting a `Message`. You are posting whatever `arg1` is.

> Also, in debugging modes, where can I see the number of threads being created? (I'm using Android Studio)

Go into the Android Debug Monitor (Tools > Android > Android Debug Monitor from the main menu), and there's a threads view in DDMS inside of there.

Comment: Okay I see. 

I also forgot to add the following code to the proguard-rules.pro
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}

Changing the parameter to the correct data-type solved my problem. 

Thank you