# EventBus OnEvent() is not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

Hi Iam using Event bus to pass data from one fragment to another Fragment

**From fragment-1 I am doing as below**

```java
@Override
public void onPause() {
    bsValues = new BoreShaftValues(strtext, strtextshaft);
    bus.post(bsValues);
    super.onPause();
}
```

**In Fragment-2 I registered bus in `OnActivitycreated`**

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    bus.register(this);
}
```

**Then I placed `OnEvent()` method in fragment-2**

```java
public void onEvent(BoreShaftValues event){
    boregradeselect.setText(event.getBoreData());
    shaftgradeselect.setText(event.getShaftData());
}
```

**Below is my `BoreshaftVales` class**

```java
public class BoreShaftValues {
    private String boredata;
    private String shaftdata;

    public BoreShaftValues(String boredata, String shaftdata){          
        this.boredata = boredata;
        this.shaftdata = shaftdata;
    }

    public String getBoreData(){
        return boredata;
    }
    public String getShaftData(){
        return shaftdata;
    }
}
```

But this `OnEvent()` method is not getting called at all. Am i doing it the rightway?

Comment: @sasikumar no errors. Unable to setText() to my Textviews

Comment: event.getBoreData() get value?

Comment: @sasikumar Not able to check event.getBoreData() since OnEvent is not calling. I can see  bus.post(bsValues); has values in it while posting

Comment: bus ?  is class? where is that code

Comment: @sasikumar include EventBus.jar to my buildpath and using as private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

Comment: @sasikumar In my activity i am replacing the fragment1 with fragment 2. And i want my data in fragment 1 to be reflected in fragment 2. so posting data in Onpause

Comment: @sasikumar First tried with onResume() it did not work then i  moved to OnPause()

Comment: @sasikumar when fragment-2 is created it should call for OnEvent() method right? .I placed a breakpoint on OnEvent().It is not going there.

Comment: @sasikumar I Placed OnEvent() code in fragment-2 .Please refer my question for how i am posting from fragment 1 and getting in fragment 2

Comment: try this public void onEvent(){
BoreShaftValues event=new BoreShaftValues();
    boregradeselect.setText(event.getBoreData());
    shaftgradeselect.setText(event.getShaftData());
}

Comment: @sasikumar Throwing exception  de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.tss.isofitsupdate.fragments.ToleranceFragment has no public methods called onEvent

Comment: sorry Unfortunately, this  onEvent() method is never called...refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474829/how-to-use-the-eventbus-onevent-method

Answer (score 1):

I typically try to tie EventBus back to the Activity and yet enable it to be loosely coupled.  So in the Fragment lifecycle I register EventBus in the onAttach and unregister it in the onDetach methods in the fragment.